# Need help for Constructing Query String - device/event.json endpoint

Tags: openfda

I'm trying to get all the filters working for Maude DB via the device/event.json endpoint.

[URL](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfMAUDE/Search.cfm)

The Filter in the website *Brand Name* matches to *device.brand_name* in the API.

Similarly, Need help to construct query string parameters for the below UI Filters

1. Report Number
2. Event Type
3. Product Problem
4. Product Class
5. Model Number

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the searchable fields for this endpoint [here](https://open.fda.gov/apis/device/event/searchable-fields/)